# PHP array resolve dot-notated keys to multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

i'm struggling with some array stuff. What i have is a function `arr_set()` where i can pass an array, a key and a value (e.g. setting a value "value" on key "sub.key" this will create `$array["sub"]["key"]` with the value "value".
I could also set an array directly (`$key` would be the value then, while `$value` is null) and assign this - works also, but with a little bug in it, because it doesn't split dot-notated keys that lay in an subarray somewhere.

Check the code:

```php
/**
 * Function to set the data
 *
 * @param      $array
 * @param      $key
 * @param null $value
 */
function arr_set(&$array, $key, $value = null) {
    if ($key === null) {
        $array[] = $value;

        return;
    }

    if (is_array($key)) {
        foreach ($key as $k => $v) {
            arr_set($array, $k, $v);
        }

        return;
    }

    $temp = &$array;
    $key = (string)$key;
    $keys = explode(".", $key);
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        if ((is_array($temp) && !array_key_exists($k, $temp)) || !is_array($temp[$k])) {
            $temp[$k] = [];
        }
        $temp = &$temp[$k];
    }

    $temp = $value;
}

$temp = [
    "live" => [
        "db.name" => "livedb",
        "db"       => [
            "host" => "localhost",
        ],
    ],
];

# Original array
$myArray = [];

# Set the $temp to the $myArray
arr_set($myArray, $temp);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($myArray, true) . "</pre>";
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [live] => Array
        (
            [db.name] => livedb
            [db] => Array
                (
                    [host] => localhost
                )

        )

)
```

Almost, but not quite perfect - you see the "db.name" key? This should actually not exist but instead the key "db" should have a subkey "name" on the same level as "host" is. Hope i provided enough information to make the problem understandable.
Thinking about how to solve this little bug cracks my brain somehow and i come to the conclusion that if there's a solution for this, it will result in a super messy, crappy, hacky piece of unperformant code. Hope it won't be but i'm giving up on this point ^^

I googled and searched a lot but couldn't find any working solution for this out there. This lib https://github.com/adbario/php-dot-notation can't do it and laravel's `array_set()` can't do it as well. Any ideas on that?

(PS: sry for bad english, german here)

Comment: It seems like `$myArray = [
    "key" => "value",
];` can be remove from your question entirely (just merge it later in your process with the recursive result.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sure, but this is not the point of my question.

Comment: Exactly, we need to isolate what you need and remove any excess from your question.

Comment: Solved it by myself. The question i now have is that why my question did get a downvote... So questions are getting downvotes, is this common practice here? Weird...

Comment: I don't find your question to be downvote-worthy, so I will upvote it now.  That said, please don't consider this page "finished".  Every page deserves a system-recognized resolution.  If you have solved your own issue, please post it as an answer and include an explanation with the intent to educate future researchers about how it works, any fringe cases that may not be accommodated, and why it is a good solution.  Marking your title with `SOLVED` is not how things are done here.  Please purge any unnecessary text from your question -- content is best when it is minimal.

Comment: Please post your answer, and when enough time has passed, you will be able to mark it with the green tick.  If someone else comes along and provides a better solution, you have the ability to move the green tick if you wish (you'll earn 5 rep points for marking another volunteer's answer).

Comment: Cool! Yeah i'll post my answer but -as already said- not right now because first i want to test my code extensively and check all eventualities. Won't put untested crap code here.

Comment: I got close, but it didn't pass with one of my more complex array structures.  If I manage to do something robust, I'll post it too.  If the currently posted answer breaks for a specific input array in your project, the right thing to do would be to offer the array to the volunteer so that they can adjust their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple solution which doesn't take into account some edge cases or error handling, but if you want a recursive solution, you might start in this direction. We could create a recursive function using your string parameter as well, but it's quite hard to work with so I created a second function for this which uses the exploded array. We use it right away we exploded the key string.

```
function arr_set(array &$array, $key, $value)
{
    $keys = explode(".", $key);
    arr_set_recursive($array, $keys, $value);
}
```

In the recursion, we pass towards the arrays we work with, the keys which left over and the value to insert. We must provide an exit from the recursion to prevent errors or stackoverflow, so we check if there is any keys left. On each step, we shift off a key from the keys array. So first we have "db", then "name". We check if we have more keys left here as well. If we do not, then we set the value to the previously shifted key. Otherwise we go one step deeper and the whole thing repeats.

```
function arr_set_recursive(array &$array, array $keys, $value)
{
    if (count($keys) > 0) {
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        if (count($keys) == 0) {
            $array[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
                $array[$key] = [];
            }
            arr_set_recursive($array[$key], $keys, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the solution here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/758bd7ed7c3cfc5bc33b4f06317be97b83958771

Comment: If you know some specific fringe cases that will cause problems, do share.

Comment: Thank you but i already managed to solve it (your solution doesn't do what i meant).

Comment: @cola SO is a knowlegde base. Not just a community where you can get a answer and don't share it with us. Can you add your own experience as answer? SO, you can mark it as Best Answer

Comment: @KoenHollander +1, i understand the concept of SO and of course i will post my solution, but not right now because first i want to test my code extensively and check all eventualities.

Comment: @cola Great! A lot of new members of SO, don't get the concept. That's why I always help people, so everyone can learn from the questions